# Responsive and dynamic background images in Vue.js

Tags: css, vue.js, responsive

I'm trying to build a vue.js front-end and the design is calling for 100% width tiles with a dynamic background image that will be passed along the rest of the content to the page. I already have the payload passing to the component that renders each tile, but I need to render the background image for each of the tiles. I also need to mention that the images are actually 3 images for each tile that need to render for each of our 3 breakpoints. So far I was able to pass one image by using `:style="'background-image: url(' + backgroundImage + ')'"` but this only serves one image per tile. My question is, what would be the best way to pass all 3 images per tile and render them correctly?

I have heard online that I should just use srcset and pass all 3 to an `<img>` tag, and make that image the background by using CSS, but that just seems unorthodox.

Is there a more elegant way to deal with responsive background images in reusable components in vue.js?

**Home Page**

```
<template>
  <div class="Home">
    <HomePageTile v-for="tile in tiles" :key="tile.title" :tile-title="tile.title" :tile-desc="tile.description" :tile-type="tile.position" :background-image="tile.backgroundImage"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HomePageTile from '@/components/HomePageTile'
import tileImage1 from '@/assets/optimized/image1.jpg'
import tileImage2 from '@/assets/optimized/image2.jpg'
import tileImage3 from '@/assets/optimized/image3.jpg'
import tileImage4 from '@/assets/optimized/image4.jpg'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {
    HomePageTile: HomePageTile
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tiles: [
        {
          title: 'Title 1',
          description: 'Content 1',
          position: 'right',
          backgroundImage: tileImage1
        }, {
          title: 'Title 2',
          description: 'Content 2',
          position: 'right',
          backgroundImage: tileImage2
        }, {
          title: 'Title 3',
          description: 'Content 3',
          position: 'right',
          backgroundImage: tileImage3
        }, {
          title: 'Title 4',
          description: 'Content 4',
          position: 'right',
          backgroundImage: tileImage4
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

**Tile Component**

```
<template>
  <div :class="tilePosition(tileType)" :style="'background-image: url(' + backgroundImage + ')'">
    <template v-if="tileType">
      <div class="home-page-tile--container home-page-tile--container__with-desc">
        <h2 class="home-page-tile--container--title">{{ tileTitle }}</h2>
        <p class="home-page-tile--container--description">{{ tileDesc }}</p>
      </div>
      <div class="home-page-tile--call-to-action" v-if="callToAction">
        <p class="home-page-tile--call-to-action--text">{{ callToAction.text }}</p>
        <Button class="home-page-tile--call-to-action--button" :button-route="callToAction.buttonPath" :button-text="callToAction.buttonText" :button-style="callToAction.buttonStyle" />
      </div>
    </template>
    <template v-else>
      <div class="home-page-tile--container">
        <h2 class="home-page-tile--container--title">{{ tileTitle }}</h2>
        <Button :button-route="buttonPath" :button-text="buttonText" button-style="pill"/>
      </div>
    </template>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Button from './Button'
export default {
  name: 'HomePageTile',
  props: {
    tileType: String,
    tileTitle: String,
    tileDesc: String,
    backgroundImage: String,
    buttonText: String,
    buttonPath: String,
    callToAction: Object
  },
  components: {
    Button: Button
  },
  data () {
    return {
      tilePosition: function (el) {
        if (el) {
          return 'home-page-tile home-page-tile__' + el
        } else {
          return 'home-page-tile'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Change the value of `backgroundImage` when you reach a breakpoint?

Comment: Show more code. Template and JS code. It is hard to figure it out as it is now.

Comment: Need more code, not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I added the code as per requested